# How to connect to MySQL from within Drupal

Tags: mysql, drupal, database-connection, drupal-7

I need to connect to mysql database and select some records in Drupal 7. How can I do it from within Drupal 7.

I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
db_set_active('default');


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
echo $result["uid"];
echo $result["name"];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 7 you are already connected to the database. You want to use the [database abstraction layer](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/group/database/7). You can use [db_select](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_select/7) if you are trying to select from the users table. See some examples in the link...

```
<?php
$result = db_select('users', 'u')
    ->fields('u')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAssoc();
?>
```